# How to save all resources downloaded from a HTTP request in PHP

Tags: php, curl, wget

Is it possible to save all resources downloaded from a HTTP request with PHP?

For example: using curl, wget or similar to get all files necessary to load the page in browser instead of only getting the HTML content of the page.

I don't want to get all links and then download each link with a direct curl. I would like a way to do it only once. I assume it's possible since in a browser I also only do one url request to get all resources.

Edit:
The point here is to simulate the browser behavior. How can I save an entire page with PHP. **If it must** be done with several steps what should be the logic to follow?
I have huge problems in getting all files from a page even after extracting links since I find it very hard to store session data and reuse it for further curls.

Comment: The browser makes the additional requests for you.

Comment: This is fundamentally incorrect: *in a browser I also only do one url request to get all resources.*

Comment: The browser makes many requests to get all the necessary resources. You don't have to take our word for it, open your browser's developer tools, go to the network tab and hit F5.

Comment: It's not incorrect. I only do one request. The rest is done by the browser not me. But I am not obviously arguing about the one request thing here. The point is how to save all images for example. Is there a way to simulate the browser behavior and store the resources of a page in PHP? What should the logic be to get this done? Get links, preserve session data, cookies and referer? Isn't there a way to just keep this data for further curls? Hope you are getting my point here

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax for that and save that as objects and show them when needed. does that works for you?

Comment: Ajax is browser involved. Ajax will never run on a cURL request.